# Finding the vector fields when lie derivative is zero

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, tensors

I am trying to figure out two things:

for the following:

$R^{2}$ is given by the coordinates $x^{1}$ and $x^{2}$ and we have a tensor $S$ such that is of type $(2,0)$ in same $R^{2}$ given by:

$S = dx^{1} ⊗ dx^{1} + dx^{2} ⊗ dx^{2}\,\,\,$,where $⊗$ is tensor product.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product

1. The vector fields of $X$ such that lie derivative $L_{X}{S}=0$ here $X$ is vector field and $S$ is tensor field. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor
2. figuring out if there exist an $X$ vector field for which  that this flow $H(t)=(H^{1}(t),H^{2}(t))^{T}$ is in a bounded set for any fixed initial value.

So I am new to this part of tensor-theory, I am having problem finding the solution for the whole problem, but I think I found the solution if we consider a simpler$S = dx^{1} ⊗ dx^{2} $ with same tensor $(2,0)$but not sure if its correct, here is what I worked out to find the vector fields:

lets assume:

$X=X^{1}(x^{1},x^{2})\partial_{1}+X^{2}(x^{1},x^{2})\partial_{2}$

is a vector filed in $R^{2}$ where $X^{1} , X^{2}$ are smooth fnuctions and so
$L_{X}{S}$ is a tensor of type $(2,0)$ which means we can do this:

$L_{X}(S = dx1 ⊗ dx2) =L_{X}dx^1  ⊗ dx^2+ dx^1 ⊗L_{X}dx^2$

let us have:

$Y=Y^{1}(x^{1},x^{2})\partial_{1}+Y^{2}(x^{1},x^{2})\partial_{2}$

and

$Z=Z^{1}(x^{1},x^{2})\partial_{1}+Z^{2}(x^{1},x^{2})\partial_{2}$

be a any vector fields in $R^{2}$ then $L_{X}{S}$ can be found from $Y$ and $Z$ and the above formula, thus we get :

$L_{X}(S =dx^{1}⊗dx^{2})(Y,Z)=(L_{X}dx^{1})(Y)dx^{2}(Z)+dx^{1}(Y)(L_{X}dx^{2})(Z)=$

$=(L_{X}dx^{1})(Y)Z^{2}+Y^{1}(L_{X}dx^{2})(Z)$

and after a long boring computation we get that :
$(L_{X}dx^{2})(Z)=Z^{1}\partial_{1}X^{2}+Z^{2}\partial_{2}X^{2}$
which can be solved for $L_{X}{S}$ giving :

$Y^{1}Z^{2}(\partial_{1}X^{1}+\partial_{2}X^{2})+Y^{2}Z^{2}\partial_{2}X^{1}+Y^{1}Z^{1}\partial_{1}X^{2}$

so to find the vector fields now we just need to let the RHS of this expression vanish for any vectorfields $Y,Z$ by letting them be anywhere over the fields $\partial_{i}$ parallel to the axis I think its reasonable to see that $L_{X}{S}=0$ is a system of PDE:

$\partial_{1}X^{1}+\partial_{2}X^{2}=0 $

$\partial_{2}X^{1}=0 $

$\partial_{1}X^{2}=0$

and solving this gives us the vector fields?

My main problem is especially with the second part, but also I would like to get a confirmation that my method makes sense and it can be applied to the bigger problem and any additional hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: First, why does the $\otimes$ here represent the Kroneker delta. It seems like it's just the normal tensor product. 
Also, you're method makes sense to some degree, but why don't you calculate the Lie derivative of $L_X dx^1$ and $L_X dx^2$ directly. It seems like it would be a lot less work. 
Unfortunately, I can't help with PDEs, although I wouldn't go to the effort of solving these ones, but calculate the ones for your other tensor

Comment: @memerson you re right about knocker delta, I translated it wrong from my native language sorry about that. So, this PDE system is an overkill in this case?

Comment: I haven't read anything carefully, but your metric tensor should be symmetric (if that's what we're trying to understand), so modify your work for $S=dx^1\otimes dx^2+dx^2\otimes dx^1$. Of course, this isn't positive-definite, so it's not actually a Riemannian metric. In the case of your original question, the vector fields $X$ have a natural interpretation in terms of their flows being isometries of the metric.

Comment: Now that I think about it more, I think you're way might work better. To compute the lie derivatives directly, you'd need to do one of two things. First is calculate the flow of an arbitrary vector field (which would be crazy). The is to instead start with an arbitrary flow, use that to calculate the lie derivative, set that equal to zero to find the flow, and then look at the vector field generated by the flow. In all of these it seems like PDEs comes up and while your method might be less direct and more computational, it also seems like it might be simpler.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I don't think they're trying to calculate the lie derivative of a metric tensor, but just the lie derivative of a given tensor on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @memerson Who knows!

Comment: At a glance the last two equations in the system should be $\partial_1 X^2 = \partial_2 X^1$ (otherwise the equation is redundant and underdetermined). Also, the answers to both (1) and (2) are in general different for different choices $S$.

Comment: @TravisWillse Yes I apologize it was a typo. You mean with (1) and (2) in the system?

Comment: No, I mean parts (1) and (2) of the original problem. Sometimes there are nonzero solutions to $\mathcal L_X S = 0$ but (for most $S$) there are not. Even among $S$ for which there are nonzero solutions, for some $S$ the flows of some of the nonzero solutions have bounded orbits, and for others none do.

Answer (score 1):

The method you describe is essentially correct (though the indices on the latter two components of the p.d.e. system are incorrect), but NB the answers to (1)-(2) very much depend on the choice of $S$. Indeed, for a generic $2$-tensor $S$ on a $2$-manifold the only vector field satisfying $\mathcal L_X S = 0$ is the zero vector field.

Working in coordinates gives a general coordinate formula for the Lie derivative:

$$(\mathcal L_X S)_{ab} = X^c \partial_c S_{ab} + \partial_a X^c S_{cb} + \partial_b X^c S_{ac} .$$

Our tensor $S = (dx^1)^2 + (dx^2)^2$ has constant coefficients with respect to the coordinate frame, so the first term on the right-hand side disappears, and specializing $(a, b)$ to $(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)$ immediately gives the analogous p.d.e. system for this case. (Since $S$ is symmetric, the equations we get from taking $(a, b)$ to be $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$ are the same, so in this sense it's easier to work with this $S$ than the nonsymmetric tensor $dx^1 \otimes dx^2$.) The system is

> \begin{align*}
> \partial_1 X^1 &= 0  \\
> \partial_1 X^2 + \partial_2 X^1 &= 0  \\
> \partial_2 X^2 &= 0 .
> \end{align*}

Notice that, e.g., the first equation tells you that $X^1$ is a function $X^1(x^2)$ of $x^2$ alone.

**Remark** If $S$ is (as in this case) a Riemannian metric, the equation $\mathcal L_X S = 0$ is the *Killing equation*, and by definition its solutions are precisely the vector fields whose flows (locally) preserve that metric.